# phpmail sending email twice

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a php script that should be sending an email when a registration is completed. This works fine where as soon as someone registered the email is sent and I receive it. However, I have noticed that sometimes I receive the same email about an hour afterwards. Sometimes it even suddenly sends me an email for a registration that was received weeks ago.

```
$key=$_GET[key];
    if(isset($key) || !empty($key)){
        $query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE value='$key'");
        while($question_list = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
            $num_questions=mysql_num_rows($query1);
            $title= $question_list['title'];
            $firstname=$question_list['firstname'];
            $lastname=$question_list['familyname'];
            $dateofbirth=$question_list['dob'];
            $gender=$question_list['gender'];
            $nationality=$question_list['nationality'];
            $email=$question_list['email'];
            $to = "userregistration@yahoo.com";
            $subject = "Registration";
            $message = "Hello! Registration, see below."."\n";
            $message.="\n";
            $message.="Title: ";
            $message.=$title."\n";
            $message.="First Name: ";
            $message.=$firstname."\n";
            $message.="Last Name: ";
            $message.=$lastname."\n";
            $message.="Gender: ";
            $message.=$gender."\n";
            $message.="Date of Birth: ";
            $message.=$dateofbirth."\n";
            $message.="Nationality: ";
            $message.=$nationality."\n";
            $message.="Email Address: ";
            $message.=$email."\n";
            $message.="Telephone: ";
            $message.=$telephone."\n";
            $from = "registration@yahoo.com";
            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$key=$_GET[key]` where did you define constant `key` ? Or did you mean `$_GE['key']` ? Caution, your script is open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your sql query to

```
"SELECT * FROM registration WHERE value='$key' LIMIT 0,1"
```

so that it will send mail only once

in you question list if you are getting 2 records from the table then you will end up sending a single mail twice.